# Inconsistent SQL responses

Tags: sql-server, ipv6, ipv4

SQL Server 2014.

**TL DR** I need to be able to query between IP ranges on a VARBINARY(16) field, but I am getting an incorrect result on the first query run whereas I get the correct result when I re-run the query a second time. Why is this happening?

I am trying to get IPGeoLocation data where the data vendor provides latitude and longitude by IP range (IPv4 and IPv6). The raw IP address range (i.e., start and end) is stored as VARCHAR(39) along with a Hex conversion in as VARBINARY(16), which was done as an UPDATE to the table using CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), IpStart). This means there are four columns total. There are two data vendors that I am vetting to see what the actual results are, so there are two tables with IPGeolocation data. Additionally, there are two non-clustered columns on each table that cover the VARCHAR(39) columns and the VARBINARY(16) columns.

I am receiving an inconsistent response from SQL Server on one of the data vendors when I query the address range BETWEEN VARCHAR(39) and VARBINARY(16). Now, here's the kicker, I am converting the VARCHAR(39) to VARBINARY(16) on the fly using CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), IpStart). My expectation is that the two queries return identical results. However, on the first run the results are different where the query BETWEEN the Hex columns is incorrect. But, when I re-run the query then the Hex column output matches. Why? Is this a caching issue in SQL Server? Is this a possible bug? Has anyone encountered this issue?

```
DECLARE @RowKey INT 
    ,@Ip VARCHAR(39) = '2600:1011:b152:d4aa:b158:af57:d0d8:ef6d'

DECLARE @IpHex VARBINARY(16) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), @Ip)  
    ,@RowKeyHex INT

SELECT @RowKey = RowKey
FROM IpGeoLocation
WHERE ProtocolKey = 7 -- 'IPV4' = 6 & 'IPV6' = 7
    AND CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), @Ip) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), NetworkStartIp) AND CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), NetworkEndIp)

SELECT @RowKeyHex = RowKey
FROM IpGeoLocation
WHERE ProtocolKey = 7 -- 'IPV4' = 6 & 'IPV6' = 7
    AND @IpHex BETWEEN NetworkStartIphex AND NetworkEndIphex

SELECT @Ip, @IpHex
     ,RowKey, ProtocolKey, ProtocolId, Latitude, Longitude, NetworkStartIp, NetworkEndIp, NetworkStartIpHex, NetworkEndIpHex
FROM IpGeoLocation
WHERE RowKey = @RowKey

SELECT @Ip, @IpHex
     ,RowKey, ProtocolKey, ProtocolId, Latitude, Longitude, NetworkStartIp, NetworkEndIp, NetworkStartIpHex, NetworkEndIpHex
FROM IpGeoLocation
WHERE RowKey = @RowKeyHex
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Post a script that contains DDL and sample data if you want others to look at the issue. However, I see you use a select statement to assign a scalar value. Perhaps you assume that a specific row within the selected rows is used as the source of the assignment? That would not be a valid assumption. If you want logic that will consistently choose a single row and assign the appropriate (and same) value to your variable, you must write your query to select the specific row.

Comment: That was an unexpected result: more than one row being returned to the scalar. This answers my question, now I need to address the multiple rows result. You should post an answer so I can mark this as answered. Thank you.